# CREATE TABLE fails in combination WITH keyword

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ddl

```
(WITH
  occupational as (
    select 
      ...
    from census
  ),
  result as (
    select
      ...
    FROM `folder.dashboard.target_table`
    LEFT JOIN occupational
    USING (keys)
  )
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `folder.dashboard.target_table_new` 
AS SELECT * FROM result
)
```

My goal is to combine the columns from `occupational` and `target_table` into `target_table_new`.

The above code fails with the following message:

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got keyword CREATE at
```

I'm executing this on google cloud console.
I have seen the following questions in SO and tried to followed the answers but to no avail.

Ref:

- [BigQuery - Create a table from results of a query that uses complex CTEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601672/bigquery-create-a-table-from-results-of-a-query-that-uses-complex-ctes)
- [Create BigQuery table from existing table, including _PARTITIONTIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474976/create-bigquery-table-from-existing-table-including-partitiontime) (i'm not even doing partitions)
- ['Create Table As' in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069022/create-table-as-in-bigquery) (the simpliest but still fails on my side)

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around `WITH ...`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen still same error. I can do select normally with the `WITH...` either with or without parenthesis.. but when I try to do create table, it just fails

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create table first with schema, then write result into table.

create table with schema (example):

```
CREATE TABLE `folder.dashboard.target_table_new` 
(id INT64, name STRING)
```

write result into table:

```
with occupational as (
    select 
      ...
    from census
  ),
  result as (
    select
      ...
    FROM `folder.dashboard.target_table`
    LEFT JOIN occupational
    USING (keys)
  )

SELECT * 
Into folder.dashboard.target_table_new
FROM result
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make my query work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `folder.dashboard.target_table_new` 
AS
(WITH
  occupational as (
    select 
      ...
    from census
  ),
  result as (
    select
      ...
    FROM `folder.dashboard.target_table`
    LEFT JOIN occupational
    USING (keys)
  )
SELECT * FROM result
)
```

I just tried to move the `create or replace table` before the `with`.

Hopefully this will help others that are failing the CTE then `create or replace table`.